# How should I punctuate a sentence beginning with 'I was wondering'?

Tags: punctuation

How do we use wondering sentences that have a question it by comma , interrogative,question mark...

I was wondering when he rejected him do John got upset **?**
I was wondering do you love me.
I was wondering you love me.

Answer (score 1):

Statements such as "I wonder why he is late" are called indirect questions. They do not ordinarily get a question mark in formal standard English, but you might see someone use a question mark there in less formal/non-standard registers (like in an email).

They would typically end in a period (or even exclamation mark if emphasized)

Answer (score 1):

The punctuation depends on whether it is a statement or a question.

"I wonder if John got upset." is a statement about what you are thinking, so it ends in a period.

"I wonder, did John get upset?" is a question, with "I wonder" serving as more of a supplementary personalization that isn't really essential to the meaning.  It would end in a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

A question mark would be the correct punctuation here, however it would be helpful to use correct tenses. I was wondering, when he rejected him **did** John **get upset**. the English language needs you to stay in the tense you started in. for example when you say "when he rejected him", did would would be the correct tense as you are referring to an event that has already happened.

Comment: is did necessary and correct? if we can use did don't we need to use a comma before.

Comment: Yes, *did* is necessary.  fishyninja1 explained why: *when he rejected him* is in the past tense, so the events took place in the past, and therefore it has to be the past tense *did*, not the present tense *do*.  (*Do* doesn't make any sense for another reason: even in the present tense, it's "John does", not "John do".)  I think the sentence reads more clearly with a comma between "him" and "did", but I don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: It is not standard to use question marks with indirect questions. Some do informally, but it is not seen in formal writing